# Difference between range() and xrange()

Tags: range, python-2.x, xrange

I am reading through a tutorial on Python and its says "There is a variant xrange() which avoids the cost of building the whole list for performance sensitive cases (in Python 3000, range() will have the good performance behavior and you can forget about xrange())." [Source](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists#range).

I am asking about Python 2.x and not Python 3.

I'm not sure what this means. Am I to understand that `range(a, b)` creates a list of all the values from `a` to `b` and then iterates over them, while `xrange(a, b)` only creates each value as it iterates over? If this is the case then performance is only improved if code does not actually iterate over the entire list and breaks early.

Can someone comment on this?

Answer (score 2):

You understood correctly.

The difference resides in the memory : when using `range()` the entire list will be allocated in memory whereas `xrange()` returns [a generator](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generators) (actually it returns an xrange object which acts as a generator)

The [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) about `xrange()` is quite clear on this subject:

> The advantage of xrange() over range() is minimal (since xrange() still has to create the values when asked for them) except when a very large range is used on a memory-starved machine or when all of the range’s elements are never used

Answer (score 1):

In python3, `range()` doesn't generate the whole sequence at once, so it's also performant:

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a range object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the start, stop and step values, calculating individual items and subranges as needed).

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)